# custom adapter for android GridView or ListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, adapter

below is ImageAdapter that extends BaseAdapter.  it contains code to set the image bitmap to the ImageView and setText method to set the text to the TextView.  but I still need to bind both the TextView and the ImageView to the parent of the adapter.  the actual gridView where each image and text will appear. how to do this?  I am missing some things in my code.

image_item is the xml layout design for a single view in a listView or gridView. it contains one ImageView and one TextView.  basically a jpeg image and below each image the title of the image that will appear.

```
     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

       private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
             mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
              return count;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
              return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
              return position;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

              if (convertView == null) {

                  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
              } else {

                  view = convertView;
              }

              ImageView i = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapterImageView);

              i.setImageBitmap(bm); // bm = bitmap object

              // bm is the bitmap returned by an intent get extras, that code not shown

              TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapterTitleView);

              t.setText("test text");

              return view;
          }


        }
```

Comment: `I still need to bind both the TextView and the ImageView to the parent of the adapter` what do you mean ? also, count is not defined, bm is not defined.

Comment: post full source code to overcame you problem and solve it..

Comment: t.setText("test text")  will set the text to TextView t, however t has no connection to the gridView that holds a textview in each view, so additional code is needed like example  t.setText(additionalFunction("test text"));  additional function needed to connect the textView to the gridView that uses the adapter.   Or am i wrong about needing to do this?

Comment: Post full source code of the adapter and Activity.

Comment: i was about to post more code when i tried it on the AVD and it works.  so i found out that there is already binding between the gridView and the textView and imageView, by this line,  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);   the actual problem was not with the code.  the problem was because the image was set so large that the textView would not show up below the imageView.  but now it appears that this adapter code actually works.

Comment: now in gridView each image has the name of the image below each image. the actual solution was reducing the size of the textview in the xml and also reducing the size of the image so they both showed up in the gridView.  i originally thought that the adapter was not working and that is why i asked the original quesion.